# Sharepoit c# how to update 'Approval workflow' programatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to update 'approval workflow' status programmaticaly as in the picture.
Please help me or orient me to any solution.

Already tried below code:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht["FormData"] = SPWorkflowStatus.Completed;
ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed] = "TRUE";
ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
ht["Com"] = "test comments";
ht["Reviewed"] = "Yes";
ht["SendSignOffEmail"] = "Yes";
ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved";
bool succed = SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(t as SPListItem, ht, true);
```

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4utW.png) to understand me better.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to change the task worklow than the workflow himself.

Since a Worklow is associated to a task. You just have to change the status of your task in order to get your instance of workflow approved.